# Setting speed of the animation function in jQuery, issue

Tags: jquery, animation

This is my function in jQuery(animation):

```
$(".sidePanel").animate({
                width : "show"
            }, {
                complete : function() {
                    $(".trigger").hide();
                    $(".trigger-reverse").show();
                    $(".sidePanel").find("p").fadeIn(200);
                    $(".filo-text").addClass("complete");
                }
            },5000,'liniear');
```

If change the value **5000** to **1000** it has no effect. Same if I remove it. Why ? What am i doing wrong ?

UPDATE: Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmfrq1dv/2/). I know it is not looking good, but you get the idea. I want to speed up the animation, when you click the "click here" div.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)? It is clear why is not working.

Comment: maybe for you it is clear, but for a beginner not, no ofsense. Maybe you can post an answer with an example. I will gladly receive it. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, `animate` can take one of the two signatures:
`.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`
or
`.animate( properties, options )`

Which applied to your case, means you can use:

```
$(".sidePanel").animate({
                  width : "show"
                },
                5000,
                'linear',
                function() {
                    $(".trigger").hide();
                    $(".trigger-reverse").show();
                    $(".sidePanel").find("p").fadeIn(200);
                    $(".filo-text").addClass("complete");
                });
```

or

```
$(".sidePanel").animate({
                  width : "show"
                }, {
                  duration: 5000,
                  easing: 'linear',
                  complete: function() {
                    $(".trigger").hide();
                    $(".trigger-reverse").show();
                    $(".sidePanel").find("p").fadeIn(200);
                    $(".filo-text").addClass("complete");
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the values 100,150,200. They are the time in ms

```
$(".trigger").hide(100);
$(".trigger-reverse").show(150);
$(".sidePanel").find("p").fadeIn(200);
```